# Type 13 mismatch error when erasing more than one target cell

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, worksheet

I am fairly new to VBA, please forgive me. This code is probably bloated and can be cleaned up (not sure how), but when I have multiple cells in the target filled with a value that fires the worksheet change event, I can delete them one at with no issue. If I delete more than one cell at a time, I end up with the type 13 mismatch error. The code is supposed to check for a value change in column c, if it is one of two values it is supposed to insert "N/A" into several other cells on that same row (some non-contiguous). If it is not that value, then it is supposed to remain blank. It is paired with a code to check that same column for a third value, if it is the third value, it is supposed to return "N/A" to a single cell in that row. The error is highlighting "If Target.Value = "Wind Sites" Or Target.Value = "Springbok 3" Then" as the issue here.

I am fairly new to VBA, please forgive me. This code is probably bloated and can be cleaned up (not sure how), but when I have multiple cells in the target filled with a value that fires the worksheet change event, I can delete them one at with no issue. If I delete more than one cell at a time, I end up with the type 13 mismatch error. The code is supposed to check for a value change in column c, if it is one of two values it is supposed to insert "N/A" into several other cells on that same row (some non-contiguous). If it is not that value, then it is supposed to remain blank. It is paired with a code to check that same column for a third value, if it is the third value, it is supposed to return "N/A" to a single cell in that row. The error is highlighting "If Target.Value = "Wind Sites" Or Target.Value = "Springbok 3" Then" as the issue here.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = Sheet4
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Target.Value = "Wind Sites" Or Target.Value = "Springbok 3" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 2) = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, 3) = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, 4) = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, 5) = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, 7) = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, 9) = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, 10) = "N/A"
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 5).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 9).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 10).ClearContents
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Galloway 1" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 8) = ""
    Else
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Value <> "Galloway 1" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 8) = "N/A"
            If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 8).ClearContents
                If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` needs to be at the top of your Sub.  `Target.Value` for a multi-cell range would be an array, and you can't compare an array with (eg) "Wind Sites"

Comment: It'd  be safer to use `Target.CountLarge`  instead of `Target.Count` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the logic of your code, `Change` event could be simiplified as below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not .Column = 3 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If .Value = "Wind Sites" Or .Value = "Springbok 3" Then
            .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4) = "N/A"
            .Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 4) = "N/A"
        Else
            .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 4).ClearContents
            .Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 4).ClearContents
        End If
        If .Value = "Galloway 1" Or .Value = "" Then
            .Offset(0, 8).ClearContents
        Else
            .Offset(0, 8) = "N/A"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your rewrite solves one of the two issues I am having, I no longer receive the mismatch error, but when I delete more than one cell in the target area (C:C) it is not clearing the content of any of the adjacent cells that are marked "N/A". Do you know what would cause the mismatch error to stop but not allow the thing that was causing the original area (deleting multiple cells in the target area)?

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Taller, thank you for your assistance, but this updated code is no longer firing the change event. I reverted back to the original you wrote.

Comment: Your test run haven't restored the setting. Restart Excel or run "Application.EnableEvents=True" in VBE Immediate window.

Comment: I was unable to get this current code to work as you wrote it. If you put the old edited code back on here, I will accept that as the answer. I restarted excel multiple times it will not fire the even change. The old code was much closer than anything I was able to come up with.

Comment: I have rollbacked the code to the previous verion.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you for your help,